# Ratio of applicants to jobs for engineering professor or assistant professor

Tags: professorship, engineering, reference-request, assistant-professor

Where can I find statistics for jobs to applicant ratios for engineering professorships or assistant professorships?

The reason I'm asking this is I'm thinking this might be the best metric to determine whether become a professor in an engineering field is "easier" (greater probability of being hired) than a humanities related field.

If the ratio I requested isn't a useful statistic, I am also open to other metrics.

Comment: Note that if 100 people apply for each and every one of  100 jobs, and all get hired, the success rate per application is one percent.  If 100 people each apply for two jobs among 100 on offer, and just 50 of them get hired, the success rate per application was 25 per cent.  This is not a good metric for ease of getting hired unless people in all fields have the same practice of how widely to apply, which they probably do not.

Comment: Broad statistics like this are unlikely to be useful. It depends on the applicant's qualifications, the type of school, the specific field and sub-field, as well as many other factors.

Comment: @BenCrowell what would you consider to be a better set of statistics to summarize the difficulty of acquiring the position I mentioned in the question?

Comment: I would suggest comparing the number of PhDs per year to the number of new faculty hired per year.  Obviously this is measuring something different than what you're asking for — it doesn't distinguish PhDs who unsuccessfully applied to faculty positions from PhDs who had no interest in staying in academia — but it does avoid the statistical pitfalls of job-to-applicant ratios.

Comment: @JeffE Has exactly the right idea about the meaningful statistic. What you're after is "What are my chances of getting hired?" So the relevant info is "What percentage of people like me got hired?" ideally you'd break that data out by prestige of program and maybe gender, age or other demographic factors too. Such data are hard to get. Philosophy has just finally gotten around to collecting some of this info here: http://dailynous.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/apdafinalreport2015.pdf

Answer (score 2):

At my institution I would say the ration is about 1:6. But this is a really bad metric for 'hardness of getting hired'. For example in the humanities typically applicants' hair is already greying, while engineering applicants almost still have their milk teeth. That is a much stronger indication that humanities jobs are much harder to get than engineering academic jobs.

Comment: What are you measuring by the 1:6 ratio?  That your institution graduates six students who are looking for academic jobs for each person you hire?

Comment: I was talking about the approximate fraction between the number of candidates that apply for a tenure track job at our institution and the number of offers we give. Of course there are many other legitimate measures - my point was that none of them are very good at estimating 'hardness off being hired'. Of the PhD graduates in our institution who try to follow an academic career, I would guesstimate that about 1/2 eventually get a tenure-track position, but this is a very crude estimate, and again is a bad measure for difficulty of the field, whatever that means...

Comment: _At my institution I would say the ration is about 1:6_ — This figure sounds **extremely** low. (On a recent faculty search, we had about 50 applications for one TT opportunity, and I would imagine similar, if not higher, numbers of applicants per opening at other places.)

Comment: @user1258240: Either you are working in a hiring system like the German one, where the calls for faculty jobs demand very specific research profiles, thereby limiting the pool, or you're thinking of the ratio of invited candidates to hires.

Comment: The number of offers you _give_ or the number of offers that are _accepted_?  (My department historically makes 2 or 3 faculty offers for every offer accepted.)

Comment: I guess I shorld have made it clear that -my institution is not in the U.S.. It's not german either, but anyway this just shows that measuring application to job ratio is a bad measure. A better one would be average number of years from starting graduate studies until entering tenure track (or getting tenure). And in There measures, getting engineering jobs is way easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that applicants per job is a statistic that is reported by departments. I've been on all sides of job searches (applicant, reviewer, bystander, administrative assistance), and that's always been a number that's stayed internal to the department.

However, for jobs in the US, a good rule of thumb is that the number of applicants will be on the order of about 100. A short application window or a very specific research profile will diminish the pool, but the number of applicants will still be substantial.

Comment: I think this varies significantly by field and by location.  My computer science department got 300 faculty applicants for each of the last three years (for varying numbers of positions).  Comparable departments in larger cities regularly get 500 applications per year.

Comment: Most of the searches in my field (Philosophy, USA) that I have known well enough to get statistics have averaged between 300 and 500 applications for a single tenure track position.